# How to find and execute?

Tags: bash, find, execute

All [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and execute examples are a variation of this (with `/bin/rm`) :

```
find /tmp -name core -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f
```

but I couldn't find how to find and execute files (assuming they are executable).

So, how to find and execute files from bash script?

I tried it like this (and similar variations) :

```
find $ROOT_PATH -executable  -name unittests_runner.exe -exec {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to add a "\;" at the end of your line, like:

```
find $ROOT_PATH -executable  -name unittests_runner.exe -exec {} \;
```

et voilá...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for `find $ROOT_PATH -executable  -name unittests_runner.exe`; do 
    `$i`
done
```

By the way:

```
`something`
```

is shorthand for

```
${something}
```

and it means "execute whatever's in there"

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like:

```
find $ROOT_PATH -executable -type f | xargs /bin/bash
```